# IE css width issue for tabs

Tags: css

The tab content displays well in all browser except IE. Is there away to correct that size issue with the IE browswer?

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/slidingtabs/horizontal.html)

Here is the CSS to control width

```
div.st_horizontal { /* The main container */    
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    /*clear:both; */
    width:655px;  /*Set the full width */  
    color:#616161;
}
```

[image]

Comment: In IE9, I can actually see next and previous arrows, which I don't see in FF 13.0.1. What version of IE you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a conditional CSS that targets only IE.

```
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" /><![endif]-->
```

and write the width in there.

But I'm looking at the link on chrome and it seems like its also not align to the edge of the tab as well.